# PowerShell and getting object properties

Tags: powershell

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -identity “GroupName” | select saMAccountName

foreach($user in $users)
{

}
```

How can I get 2 properties from here. I need the sAMAccountName and the Office

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, verify if you want to get the "Office" property, or "physicalDeliveryOfficeName"

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Get-ADUser $user -Properties Office | select SamAccountName,Office
}
```

Also, you don't need to select anything for your $users object to work

```
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity GroupName
```

A great thing about working with Active Directory cmdlets is that you can usually throw the entire object at it, and it will work because of:

```
[parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
```

Adding an example that worked for exporting to CSV:

```
Get-ADUser $user -Properties Office | select SamAccountName,Office | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\PSResults\foo.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate that. I was trying to add different AD attributes to the first line of code and it wasn't working the way I wanted.

Comment: One question. I am exporting this to CSV. When I run this, I get "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection". Is there anyway to get the actual value?

Comment: I don't remember right off, I know I've had issues with it before, but I just tested and it worked. I'll edit it in. Basically, you're sending an object down the pipepline, but the CSV wants to put in strings.